# In-call status bar HIG guidelines issue

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, hig

I have a view which has an imageview at the bottom
but when I simulate a call it partially hides it and goes below the screen.
 I am not sure about this but according to the ios HIG guidelines my app should handle this accordingly. See this..

> Make sure your UI can handle the double-high status bar. The double-high status bar appears during events such as in-progress phone calls, audio recording, and tethering. In unprepared applications the extra height of this bar can cause layout problems. For example, the UI can become pushed down or covered. In a multitasking environment, it’s especially important to be able to handle the double-high status bar properly because there are likely to be more applications that can cause it to appear. You can trigger the double-high status bar during testing to help you find and correct any views that don’t handle it well. (To learn how to do this using iOS Simulator, see “Manipulating the Hardware” in Tools Workflow Guide for iOS.)

My question is what I am I supposed to do here and how Should I handle this..?

Comment: Resize your main view to accommodate the extra height taken by the status bar. *How* you do it depends on the layout of your image with respect to the rest of the view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should listen these two call-backs of UIApplicationDelegate:

```
application:willChangeStatusBarFrame:

application:didChangeStatusBarFrame:
```

And Resize your main view to accordingly.

Comment: Thanks, I was trying this along with auto resizing property of views but it was not working due to some reason. I quit xcode and started it again and Voila its working.